# How to apply PHP GD and image functions to image retrieved from mySQL DB?

Tags: php, mysql, gd

I am new to PHP and a little rusty when it comes to programming in general...

I have images on my Mac that I select and upload via PHP as blobs in a mySQL DB.
They will then be embedded in a gallery on a website but I want to blur them first.
After I read them from the DB, I am using a combination of image functions for this but I am not sure the image I pass is in the right format since they are not rendered on the website.

Code snippets below.

**Upload (works fine):**

```php
for ($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++) {
            $name = basename($_FILES['image']['name'][$i]);
            $type = pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            $size = $_FILES['image']['size'][$i];
            $temp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][$i];
            $allowTypes = array('jpg', 'png', 'jpeg', 'gif');
            if (in_array($type, $allowTypes)) {
                $imgContent = addslashes(file_get_contents($temp));
                // Insert image content into database
                $insert = $db->query("INSERT into images (filename, image, page, created) VALUES ('$name','" . $imgContent . "', '$page', NOW())");
                if ($insert) {
                    $status = 'success';
                    $statusMsg = "File uploaded successfully.";
                } else {
                    $statusMsg = "File upload failed, please try again.";
                }
            } else {
                $statusMsg = 'Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG, & GIF files are allowed to upload.';
            }
        }
```

**Retrieve images from DB and render them after calling a blur function (the 2nd IMG tag that I commented out is the one that works without blurring the images):**

```php
<?php
// Include the database configuration file
require_once 'dbConfig.php';
include 'blurimage.php';
// Get image data from database
$sql = "SELECT image FROM images ORDER BY id DESC";
$result = $db->query($sql);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
    <title>Retrieve Images from Database using PHP by CodexWorld</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!-- Custom stylesheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Retrieve Images from Database using PHP</h1>
        <div class="gallery">
            <?php if ($result->num_rows > 0) { ?>
                <?php while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
                    <?php $image = $row['image']; ?>
                    <?php ?>
                    <div class="img-box">
                        <img src="<?php blur($image)?>" 
                        <!-- <img src="data:image/jpg;charset=utf8;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($row['image']); ?>" /> -->
                    </div>
                <?php } ?>
            <?php } else { ?>
                <p class="status error">Image(s) not found...</p>
            <?php } ?>
        </div>

        <a href="index.php">Upload images</a>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**Blur function in separate blurimage.php page:**

```php
<?php

function blur($image)
{
  // $start = microtime(true);

  /* Scale by 25% and apply Gaussian blur */
  $s_img1 = imagecreatetruecolor(160, 120);
  imagecopyresampled($s_img1, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, 160, 120, 640, 480);
  imagefilter($s_img1, IMG_FILTER_GAUSSIAN_BLUR);

  /* Scale result by 200% and blur again */
  $s_img2 = imagecreatetruecolor(320, 240);
  imagecopyresampled($s_img2, $s_img1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 320, 240, 160, 120);
  imagedestroy($s_img1);
  imagefilter($s_img2, IMG_FILTER_GAUSSIAN_BLUR);

  /* Scale result back to original size and blur one more time */
  imagecopyresampled($image, $s_img2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 640, 480, 320, 240);
  imagedestroy($s_img2);
  imagefilter($image, IMG_FILTER_GAUSSIAN_BLUR);
  //$end =  microtime(true);
  //$howlong = $end - $start;
  return $image;
}
?>
```

I also tried to pass the blob directly from the DB without any transformation but that didn't work either as expected.

Comment: You need to check if you get any errors, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display. The arguments for the `image*()` functions are usually a `GdImage` handle, not an image byte array. Also check the resulting HTML code, that was generated by the PHP script, how the `<img src="..` tag look like.

Comment: You need to start with `imagecreatefromstring`, to create a GD image resource again from the _string value_ you are reading from your database. (And if you really still think `addslashes` was the correct way to handle data for database insertion, please go read up on how to actually handle this properly.)